# create random integers for quiz using plist

Tags: objective-c

I would like to have user click on a button to generate a ten-question quiz in the form of "a +/- b = c" where the values for a and b are from +10 to -10 and are randomly assigned for the ten questions. Also, the questions should randomly switch between addition and subtraction. How do I populate the plist file correctly? How do I use `arc4random` to create ten questions with random integers?

I thought it would be neat to have questions display in a one-column picker where user can scroll through the questions or just have text at a certain `CGPoint` on screen.

Instead, I have created a plist with 84 different possible questions and I want to randomly choose 10 from plist to create the quiz each time a user clicks on button. I have this so far:

```
NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"global" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsofFile:plistFile];
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"1"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"2"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"3"]);
```

global is the name of plist, `@"1"`, `@"2"`, `@"3"` etc are the names of the 84 diff Q's I put in plist. How do I randomly choose 10 of the 84 NSLogs?

Comment: What does the plist have to do with anything?

Comment: What if I did this? I have created a plist with; key1 = (+10) + (+10), key 2 = (+10) + (+9), key 3 = etc...this will create 84 different possible questions, so now I want to randomly select 10 to create the quiz when user clicks button. I have this so far... NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"global" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsofFile:plistFile];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"1"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"2"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"3"]);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `NSDictionary`, use `NSArray` if your keys are just numbers. You could then do

```
NSString *randomString = [array objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [array count])];
```

to pick a random element.

**However**, I would *really* advice against looking it up in a plist if it's just different combinations of random numbers. Writing out all those combinations by hand is just a waste of time. That's what computers are for!

Old, but still relevant answer:

To generate a random number between `-10`and `10`:

```
int a = (arc4random() % 21) - 10;
```

You could also make a function like this:

```
int randomIntegerInRange(int min, int max)
{
    int range = max - min + 1;
    return min + arc4random() % range;
}
```