# randomly choose from plist

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create random integers for quiz using plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261252/create-random-integers-for-quiz-using-plist)

Using xcode, how do I randomly choose from my plist? I have created 84 questions in my plist and want to randomly choose 10 to create a quiz when user clicks button.

So far I have

```
NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"global" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsofFile:plistFile];
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"1"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"2"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"3"]);
```

Global is the plist name, @"1", @"2", etc are the names for each different question. This is my long way of creating a quiz with random questions.

Comment: Very much a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

If your keys really are `@"1"`, `@"2"`, etc, then you can just choose a random number and select that object. For example,

```
int i = (arc4random() % 84) + 1;
[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
```

However, in this case it seems to me that you should instead have an `NSArray` of questions instead of an `NSDictionary`. Then you could simply do

```
int i = arc4random() % 84;
[questionArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

To get `10` distinct random numbers chosen from `84` possibilities, the easiest is probably just to keep an `NSMutableArray` of the numbers. Then, generate another random number as above and before adding it to the array, check that it isn't already there. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *questionNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i;
while ([questionNumbers count] < 10) {
    i = arc4random() % 84;
    if (![questionNumbers containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]) {
        [questionNumbers addObject:[NSNumber  numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to release `questionNumbers` at some point if you choose this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c). Then, you need to have your own algorithm to keep it unique 10 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution to another question to accomplish this:

[What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Using the `-shuffle` method from that solution, you can do the following:

```
- (NSArray *)getRandomObjectsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict numObjects:(NSInteger)numObjects
{
    NSMutableArray *keys = [[[dict allKeys] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [keys shuffle];

    numObjects = MIN(numObjects, [keys count]);

    NSMutableArray randomObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        [randomObjects addObject:[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:randomObjects];
}
```

This will work for any `NSDictionary`, regardless of what the keys are.